# How to write click function for edit icon in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new to cypress, how to write click fun for edit icon, below I shared the html code

[image: html code]

[![for delete][3]][3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding the card with name 'cypress' and clicking the edit button

```js
cy.contains('.MuiCardContent-root', 'cypress').within(() => {
  cy.get('svg.MuiSvgIcon-root').eq(0)  // 1st button is edit
    .click()
})
```

Comment: still its not working

Comment: what error is you are getting ?

Comment: Expected to find element: a, but never found it. I am getting this error

Answer (score 4):

you can use get() like querySelector:

```
let selector = 'svg.MuiIconButton-root'
cy.get(selector).click()
```

Comment: still it's not working

Comment: ok. Try: `let selector = 'MuiIconButton-root'`. You use get like JS QuerySelector. Sometime you have multiple Layers behind and anchor link. and you have to specified which layer you want. But i thing that is not the problem here. Give a feedback it works ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can right click on the element in your dev tools and copy the selector then do:

```
cy.get('selector').click()
```

Comment: still its not working

Comment: Maybe try it with `.click({ force: true })`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
cy.get('svg.MuiSvgIcon-root').click()
```

If the above doesn't work, you can add `{force: true}` and try:

```js
cy.get('svg.MuiSvgIcon-root').click({force: true})
```

If you want to click any particular icon, you have to use the `eq()` command:

```js
cy.get('svg.MuiSvgIcon-root').eq(0).click() //clicks the first svg icon
```

You can try using this:

```js
cy.get('a[role="button"]').eq(0).click()
```

Comment: still it's not working

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: pls check  i updated my edit page

Comment: for edit and delete same 'svg.MuiSvgIcon-root', i think thats y its not working ,rght?

Comment: Then please share the HTML for the Delete icon button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238272/discussion-between-user2345-and-alapan-das).

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute (this a best practice from [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements)) to your html element

```
<span [attr.data-cy]="nav-menu-mat-icon"></span>
```

and then select it from your steps file:

```
get('nav-menu-mat-icon').click();
```

Comment: It looks as though you have an extra character 'e' in your attribute name `get('nav-menu-mat-icone')...`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an example repo to share, it may be tough to understand the problem in whole. Depending on your app behavior, I'd recommend appending `.should('be.visible')` to your `.get()` as to continuously requery for your element.